# How to use xml instead of yml after making bundles

Tags: symfony

Mybundle was already set upped as using services.yml

But I want to use services.xml.

So I changed in DependacyInjection/MybundleExtension.php

```
#$loader->load('services.yml');     
$loader->load('services.xml');
```

but it says

```
Unable to parse in      "\/Users\/whitebear\/httproot\/mutor\/src\/Acme\/MyBundle\/DependencyInjection\/..\/Resources\/config\/services.xml" at line 1 (near "").
```

my services.xml here though,I think it is correct(just copy and pasted from other site)

```
<services>
    <service id="acme.demobundle.calendar_listener" class="Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
        <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="calendar.load_events" method="loadEvents" />
    </service>

</services>
```

Is there another place I have to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you use `XmlFileLoader`?

```
$loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
$loader->load('services.xml');
```

Also standart xml structure include `container` tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <parameters>
        ...
    </parameters>

    <services>
        <service id="...">
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```